# How to increment an alphanumeric ID through code in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in database which contains an alphanumeric ID field, and the ID field contains two letters and three numbers like 'AA001'.

I want to auto increment the ID in my code. First I'll increment the number till 999 and when the number becomes 999, the letter sequence will change. e.g. from 'AA999' to 'AB001'.

How can I do this in `C#`?

Comment: I don't think this can be done automatically. Try to make a procedure for inserting items which will perform the ID increase logic.

Comment: I want to increase the ID when I click the button 'Add'

Comment: The button will call the stored procedure to do that.

Comment: @SimpleVar I think the other way is to make a default constraint to the ID column and additionally make a TRIGGER AFTER INSERT that would update this ID column

Comment: @Pellared I assume there are other ways also. None are automatic though.

Comment: Just have a standard numeric `IDENTITY` column and use a formula to map to your desired format.

Comment: @SimpleVar You mean "out-of-the-box" :) Both are automatic

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa What button are you talking about? In some application? Maybe you could do it even on the application level if the database is only used by a single application.

Comment: When you say "auto-increase" do you mean calculate that in code in C#?

Comment: @Pellared I call it automatic if you check a box and it does it for you, I guess. You could call a stored procedure automatic from the POV of the application as well...

Comment: @Pellared I want to do it in the application level, the button adding the ID and other fields to sql database

Comment: @ArghyaC Yes I mean that calculate the code in C#, and then insert it to database

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa So what are asking for? To give some code in C# to "increment" the ID?

Comment: @SimpleVar can you get me the the stored procedure to do what I want? .. the stored procedure is serve its purpose

Comment: @Pellared I ask for increase the text like that : AA001,AA002,AA003 ........ AA999,AB001,AB002,AB003......

Comment: All friends, Excuse me for poor English

Comment: The MartinSmith's answer is the best thing you can probably, however if yoy want C# code than edit your question and write that you want "C# code to increment the ID in the following pattern"

Comment: @MartinSmith solve my problem ... thank you for all

Comment: Do you really intend to skip AB000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have a standard numeric `IDENTITY` column and use a formula to map to your desired format.

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (
     ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     C AS CHAR(65 + ID / 26000) + CHAR(65 + ID%26000 / 1000) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ID % 1000 AS VARCHAR), 3)
  )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e748a/1)

Potentially you could index the computed column to support efficient lookups against values like `'AA001'` but I wouldn't bother personally. I'd just convert these to their numeric equivalents and do lookups against the ID column instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin Smith .. this is solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do in `C#`, you can use this method

```
private static string GetNextId(string seed)
{
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string nextId = string.Empty;

    if (seed == "ZZ999")
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("I can handle till ZZ999 only!");

    var intPart = int.Parse(seed.Substring(2, 3));
    if (intPart < 999)
        nextId = seed.Substring(0, 2) + (++intPart).ToString("000");
    else
    {
        var char2idx = letters.IndexOf(seed.Substring(1, 1));
        if (char2idx < letters.Length - 1)
            nextId = seed.Substring(0, 1) + letters.Substring(++char2idx, 1) + "001";
        else
        {
            var char1idx = letters.IndexOf(seed.Substring(0, 1));
            nextId = letters.Substring(++char1idx, 1) + "A001";
        }
    }
    return nextId;
}
```

Comment: your answer is excellent and I will use it .. I really thank you very much.

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa glad that the answer helped. I just made a small fix, check `if (char2idx < letters.Length - 1)` and fix in your code.

Comment: Yes, I Changed it, when the number equals AZ999 then error is appear. but now the error is fixed

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa if you run this under conditions of concurrency you will need to add something to prevent two threads calling this function with the same seed.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, that's a very valid point. I missed to mention.

Comment: @MartinSmith I take it into consideration.. thanx